# Generates a set of random number from Binomial distribution using a set of probabilities without using any loop (like for loop)in R

Tags: r

How to generates a set of random number from Binomial distribution using a set of probabilities of same dimension without using any loop (like for loop)in R? i.e I want to generates a set of random number using different probability.

Comment: The loop based approach you've used so far, what does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly knowing what you want, but I would go like this:

```
N=1000
n=3
dat=data.table::data.table(p=runif(N,0,1))
dat[, X:= rbinom(N, n, p) ]
```

You can change n for the # of outcomes, N for the dimension, p for the probabilities you have.